# Input box and css altering colors

Tags: javascript, css, user-interface, frontend

I have a input box which looks like below,

```
<input id="basic-search" type="text" value="Enter keyword or phrase" title="basic-search" class="form-text" size="38" onclick = "this.className = 'focused'; javascript:Reset();" onblur = "javascript:Reset();" />
```

and css for .focused and form-text is,

```
.focused {
color:black;
}

.form-text
{
    background-color: #FFF;
    color: #CCC;
}
```

The input box on load has the content 'Enter keyword or phrase' which is grey initially. Onclick on this box and on typo the font color changes to black(works good). When the delete the contents, tab to next field or on mouse press the content 'Enter keyword or phrase' changes to black. It should still be grey. What change should i make in the css? any inputs would help. Thanks.

Note: I noticed the 'title' field in stackoverflow works as I would want. I want my boc to work the same way.

Comment: You certainly don't need the javascript: URL scheme, unless you've defined the base script language to be VBScript somewhere else in your page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use onfocus instead of onclick. Also, for your onblur, append the css class:

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QybRX/14/

```
<input id="basic-search" type="text" value="Enter keyword or phrase" title="basic-search" class="form-text" size="38" onfocus="this.value=''; this.className = 'focused'; javascript:Reset();" onblur = "basicSearch()" />
<input type="text"/>

<script>    
    function basicSearch()
    {
        var element = document.getElementById("basic-search");

        if ( element.value.length == 0 )
        {
            element.value = 'Enter keyword or phrase';
            element.className = 'form-text';
        }
        else
        {
            element.className = 'focused';
        }

        javascript:Reset();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: when you move out of the input box the field is greyed out however

Comment: @javaiText I thought you wanted it to be gray when the user moves on? Perhaps I read your question wrong.. You want it black?

Comment: if there is any text then it should be black when you move out of the input box...if the content is deleted and u move out of the box then the default message appears and it should be grey...much similar to the 'title' input box in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is you are adding the "focused" class to the input field when a user clicks it, but that class is never being removed.  You either need to remove the class onblur, or switch to using the `:focus` selector in CSS, like so:

```
.form-text
{
  background-color: #FFF;
  color: #CCC;
}

#basic-search:focus
{
  color: black;
}
```